# Autosar function declaration

Tags: function, declaration, autosar

I am working on an Autosar project developing a SWC(Software Component) using C, I encountered a new function declaration that I don't understand as following :

```
FUNC(void, RTE_SWC_CODE) SWC_Task(uint8 Argument) 
{
   //Code goes here
}
```

I searched for this type of declaration on the internet and I didn't find anything explaining it right.

what I don't understand is the `FUNC(Void, RTE_SWC_CODE)`

Do `Void` refers to the type of return?

And `RTE_SWC_CODE` is referring to what for the function?

`RTE_SWC_CODE`  is defined in another `rte_file.h` like this

```
#define RTE_SWC_CODE
```

Comment: Maybe you should have taken a look into the AUTOSAR_SWS_CompilerAbstraction document and in AUTOSAR_SWS_MemoryMapping. It is all about abstraction from different compilers and processor/controller architectures and not polluting the code with all the different architecture/compiler specific pragmas or __attribute__ @far/@near, inline vs _inline vs __inline__, @interrupt vs _interrupt or _at() ... , which have been introduced by the vast amount of compilers available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AUTOSAR there is one specification related to [compiler abstraction](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/classic/4-3/AUTOSAR_SWS_CompilerAbstraction.pdf) refer that specification.`FUNC` is a macro defined in Compiler.h header file.The definition of macro looks like below

```
#define FUNC(type, memclass) type memclass 
rettype     return type of the function   
memclass    classification of the function itself
```

In your case it would be like this

```
void RTE_SWC_CODE SWC_Task(uint8 Argument) //After preprocssing
```

Comment: `RTE_SWC_CODE` will also be replaced, so if it's not defined, you'll get the `void SWC_Task(uint8 Argument)` out of it.